# How do I prevent }{ in the json file when generating an auto generated json file?

Tags: python, json

The problem is }{ being added automatically inbetween the image and id 2. Should I add a check to prevent this?
Python code that generates the json file and the json file that is generated:

````
def generate_pokemon_image_db():
    with open("Image.json", "w") as file:
        for i in range(1, 3):
            p = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/{}'.format(i))
            pk = p.json()
            imgr_result = imgr_client.upload_from_path("D:\\json_generator\\Convert\\{}.png".format(i), config=None, anon=True)['link']
            data = {"Id": pk['id'],
                    "Name": pk['name'],
                    "Image": imgr_result}
            json.dump(data, file, indent=1) ```


{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "bulbasaur",
  "Image": "https://i.imgur.com/UBMWUCJ.png"
}{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "ivysaur",
  "Image": "https://i.imgur.com/0cFH8Bu.png"
}
````

Comment: Try to open the json file in read mode, store it, add your data into the variable, close it and open again the file but in write mode and dump it

Comment: You can't just concatenate JSON strings and expect a valid JSON string back.

Comment: You would not want to strip the `}{`. What you'd want would be to append each into a list then call `json.dump` with that list.

Comment: fixed the generation issue - now it generates both as needed - {
 "1": {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "bulbasaur",
  "Image": "https://i.imgur.com/wZRRwBq.png"
 },
 "2": {
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "ivysaur",
  "Image": "https://i.imgur.com/2cZ7fQO.png"
 }
}